# Encoding of request headers in REST Spring Boot controller

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, spring-boot, http-headers, iso-8859-1

**TLDR;**

Some UTF-8 headers are encoded two times when controller method is called if default charset of the application is UTF-8.
Where encoding is processed in spring MVC and how to control it ?

**Details**

We have the following problems with a header value in a REST controller

We use a SSO service that works as a proxy and injects some extra headers into the request. The injected values are mail, givenname, lastname and so.

The proxy injects **UTF-8** encoded values in header (we have checked with tcpdump and wireshark)

```
GET /api/v1/foo/bar HTTP/1.1
Host: blabla.fr
....
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
...
givenName: Gérard
```

Our controllers are like this one

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/foo")
public class FooController {

@RequestMapping("/bar")
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> bar(@RequestHeader("foo") String foo, @RequestHeader("givenname") String firstname) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    ArrayList<String> list = Lists.newArrayList(
        "FOO:                                  " + foo,
        "CHARSET:                              " + Charset.defaultCharset().name(),
        "FOO WITH DEFAULT CHARSET:             " + asHexList(foo),
        "FOO WITH UTF8:                        " + asHexList(new String(foo.getBytes("UTF-8"))),
        "INJECTED HEADER WITH DEFAULT CHARSET: " + asHexList(firstname),
        "INJECTED HEADER WITH UTF8:            " + asHexList(new String(firstname.getBytes("UTF-8")))
      );
    return ResponseEntity.ok( list  );
  }
}    
/**
  * Print a concatenated list of hexa représentation of the string's bytes
  * assert asHexList(new String("é", "UTF-8"))equals("c3 e9")
  * @param String s
  * @return String 
*/
public String asHexList(String s) {...}
```

And we have observed the following behaviors

When system's LANG is fr_FR.ISO-8859-1, then the return is

```
[
"FOO:                                 Gérard",
"CHARSET:                              ISO-8859-1",
"FOO WITH DEFAULT CHARSET:             47 e9 72 61 72 64",
"FOO WITH UTF8:                        47 c3 a9 72 61 72 64",
"INJECTED HEADER WITH DEFAULT CHARSET: 47 c3 a9 72 61 72 64",
"INJECTED HEADER WITH UTF8:            47 c3 83 c2 a9 72 61 72 64"
]
```

and when LANG is fr_FR.UTF-8 we have

```
[
"FOO:                                 Gérard",
"CHARSET:                              UTF-8",
"FOO WITH DEFAULT CHARSET:             47 c3 a9 72 61 72 64",
"FOO WITH UTF8:                        47 c3 a9 72 61 72 64",
"INJECTED HEADER WITH DEFAULT CHARSET: 47 c3 83 c2 a9 72 61 72 64",
"INJECTED HEADER WITH UTF8:            47 c3 83 c2 a9 72 61 72 64"
]
```

We can see

- when application's charset is "ISO-8859-1", custom header ('foo') is encoded in "ISO-8859-1" (é=>e9) and injected header is encoded in "UTF-8" (é=>c3 a9)
- when application's charset is "UTF-8", custom header ('foo') is encoded in "UTF-8" (é=>c3 a9) and injected header is encoded in "UTF-8" **TWICE** (é=>c3 a9=>c3 83 c2 a9)

Where encoding is processed in spring MVC and how to control it ?
Which are the relations between LANG, file.enconding and default charset in Spring ?

We are in 1.3.3.RELEASE spring boot that embed spring-web 4.2.5-RELEASE.

Your help would be very welcomed.

Comment: 5 years ago... Don't have answer (have the same type of problem). I'm just supporting the FR team ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using tomcat web server. So take a look at class `ByteChunk`, who actually flush headers from String to bytes in default `ISO-8859-1` charset.

```java
    /**
     * Default encoding used to convert to strings. It should be UTF8, as most
     * standards seem to converge, but the servlet API requires 8859_1, and this
     * object is used mostly for servlets.
     */
    public static final Charset DEFAULT_CHARSET = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1;
```

Even worse, Spring Mvc doesn't provide any chance for us to specify the correct charset to encode/decode header values.

Finally, I fixed my problem by decoding my `UTF-8` string bytes to `ISO-8859-1` format advance, so later `ByteChunk` will encode it correctly.

```java
headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, 
  new String(("attachment; filename=" + attachment.filename).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
             StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
```