# Spring boot: header value encoding

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, character-encoding

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/userlogin'
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br'
  -H 'GICAR: UNITAT_MAJOR=PRESIDÈNCIA'
```

As you can see, browser is sending a header with a content with `È` character.

I need to deal with it in to service:

```
LOG.debug("Default Cahrset: {}", Charset.defaultCharset().displayName());
String headerValue = request.getHeader(EspaiDocConstants.Headers.GICAR_HEADER);
LOG.debug("Header value: {}", headerValue);
```

The output is:

```
Default Cahrset: UTF-8
UNITAT_MAJOR=PRESIDÃNCIA
```

As you can see, `È` is chaged to `Ã`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've run into the same issue. I verified that charset in service is set to `UTF-8`. Also, if `É` is provided in requestBody, it is parsed correctly. It's only in case of headers that it reads it as `Ã`

Comment: As this is an old thread, did you find a solution to this? I see one way would be to add some code to manually parse it into `UTF-8`. Wondering if there's any other solution.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77414166/482533. Should be the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to the curl command :

`-H "charset=utf-8"`